# VBScript, purpose of colon?

Tags: vbscript

What is the purpose of the colon?

e. g.:

```
Dim objConn : Set objConn = OpenConnection()`
```

Is the colon used to combine the two statements into one line? I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, the code would work exactly the same on two lines; the colon's just a statement separator.

Comment: Then why is this not working ?? `Function Pad(s) : Pad = Right("00" & s, 2) : End Function`. It's throwing `syntax error` on that same line..

Comment: @VickyDev That's a new question -- though, just for fun, it does work for me (though it may not do what you intended). `Function Pad(s) : Pad = Right("00" & s, 2) : End Function : str = Pad("spam")` gives me `am` in `str`, which seems right -- no errors. **But try asking a _new_ question and see if someone can help.**

Answer (score 20):

You can put two (or more) lines of code in one line.  It's most often used, as in your example, to declare and set a variable on one line.

Think of it like a semicolon in every other language, except optional.

Answer (score 9):

Yes this is correct.  In VB style languages, including VBScript, the colon is an end of statement token.  It allows you to place several statements on the same line.

Comment: Then why is this not working ?? `Function Pad(s) : Pad = Right("00" & s, 2) : End Function`. It's throwing `syntax error` on that same line..

Answer (score 6):

What you have stated is correct. The purpose of the colon is to combine 2 otherwise separate lines into a single line. It works on most statements, but not all.